# Tool Bar visibility in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am creating a plugin for Qgis 2.6 and when my plugin loads up i want to disable the visibility of some of the tool bar. I was able to set the visibility for various tool bars like

```
    self.iface.digitizeToolBar().setVisible(True)
    self.iface.mapNavToolToolBar().setVisible(True)
    self.iface.advancedDigitizeToolBar().setVisible(True)
    self.iface.pluginToolBar().setVisible(True)
    self.iface.layerToolBar().setVisible(True)

    self.iface.databaseToolBar().setVisible(False)
    self.iface.fileToolBar().setVisible(False)
    self.iface.helpToolBar().setVisible(False)
    self.iface.vectorToolBar().setVisible(False)
    self.iface.rasterToolBar().setVisible(False)
    self.iface.webToolBar().setVisible(False)
    self.iface.attributesToolBar().setVisible(False)
```

Apart from this tool bars I  have other tool bars like Manage Layer, Grass, Label but I am not able to get the reference for this tool bar from the iface to set the visibility.

http://doc.qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html#a882199db87f1b58bd5fc9b3d5db00d28
This documentation does not expose this tool bars.

Comment: It will be valueable if you edit your question to explain what are you doing; and display your full source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that in this way, from the QGIS Python console:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QToolBar
iface.mainWindow().findChild(QToolBar,'mLabelToolBar').setVisible(False)
iface.mainWindow().findChild(QToolBar,'mLayerToolBar').setVisible(False)
```

I got the tool bar names (e.g., mLabelToolBar and mLayerToolBar) from `Settings->Customization...->Toolbars`. Check it to know the Grass tool bar name (I don't have that one available).

Comment: I did it other way just in case this would be helpful to some one else  using for x in iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QToolbar): print x.objectName() to get all the names of toolBar