# Finding name of QGIS toolbar in Python?

Tags: pyqgis, toolbar

I want to run python script. I don't know the name of toolbar in python script language : menu toolbar, browser panel toolbar, and label toolbar.
The screenshots of the toolbars for which I don't know the python names of are:

[image]

[image]

[image]

To test the name of toolbar is true, I try to type in python script like this :

```
iface.menuToolBar().setVisible(False)

iface.browserpanelToolBar().setVisible(False)

iface.labelToolBar().setVisible(False)
```

But, the toolbar is still be visible. So the name of these toolbar is false. So, what the name of these toolbar?

Comment: If you direct the pointer to the edge of toolbar, it will give you the name. I give you screenshot the toolbar : https://1drv.ms/f/s!Amfzr7zpdbRqjEBvvp8DkqD3F27m

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the answer and comments on this post: [Tool Bar visibility in PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142736/tool-bar-visibility-in-pyqgis), we can determine the name of these objects and set their visibility to `False`. If you go to the menubar and select `Settings > Customization`, you can see the types of objects used. In your case:

- Menu Toolbar = [QMenuBar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmenubar.html)
- Browser Panel = [QDockWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdockwidget.html)
- Label Toolbar = [QToolBar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtoolbar.html)

So, we can find all the names of objects which fall under each of those object types by using:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QToolBar, QDockWidget, QMenuBar

# Get list of all ToolBars
for x in iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QToolBar): 
    print x.objectName()

# Get list of all Dockwidgets
for x in iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QDockWidget): 
    print x.objectName()

# Get name of MenuBar
for x in iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QMenuBar): 
    print x.objectName()
```

Once we have determined the names of the objects you are interested in, we can hide them:

- Menu Toolbar: `iface.mainWindow().menuBar().setVisible(False)`
- Browser Panel: `iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget,'Browser').setVisible(False)`
- Label Toolbar: `iface.mainWindow().findChild(QToolBar,'mLabelToolBar').setVisible(False)`