# Name of children of toolbar in QGIS python and how to disable?

Tags: pyqgis, toolbar

There are name of toolbar you can see in : 
[Finding name of QGIS toolbar in Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227876/name-of-qgis-toolbar-in-python)

But, I want to know the name of children of toolbar. For example, the children of mapNavToolBar are touch zoom and pan; pan map; pan map to selection; zoom in; zoom out; etc. Then if we know the name, how to disable in python?

For example to disable menuBar you can type the script :

```
iface.mainWindow().menuBar().setVisible(False)
```

But, for the child?

I want to show not all mapNavToolBar, Layers Panel, and menuBar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, we can find all object names of the icons in the `mapNavToolBar` using:

```
for icon in iface.mapNavToolToolBar().actions(): 
    print icon.objectName()
```

Decide which ones you want to modify then add them to a list:

```
icon_list = ['mActionDraw', 'mActionPan', 'mActionZoomIn']
```

Now, you can either:

- Hide them:

  ```
  for icon in iface.mapNavToolToolBar().actions(): 
      if icon.objectName() in icon_list:
          icon.setVisible(False)
  ```

---

- Or disable them:

  ```
  for icon in iface.mapNavToolToolBar().actions(): 
      if icon.objectName() in icon_list:
          icon.setEnabled(False)
  ```

Comment: Joseph, I have tried your sintax, but the toolbar is still there. It just can't be clicked. So, how to remove the toolbar? I change the code : icons.setEnabled(False) to become icons.setVisible(False). But nothing happen. I want to remove some of toolbar.

Comment: @mega - Edited my post which allows you to hide (or disable) certain icons in a toolbar :)

Comment: Joseph, it is work. Thanks. By the way, I try to show Layers Panel children name. I type : for icon in iface.Layers().actions():       print icon.objectName(). It is error. I want to hide layer panel children too.

Comment: @mega - Most welcome, glad it worked! The Layers Panel is part of the QDockWidget so you will need to use: `from PyQt4.QtGui import QDockWidget` `for x in iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QDockWidget):` `if x.objectName() == 'Layers':` `x.hide()`

Comment: I mean, how to show the children name of Layers Panel in python? The children name are 'Open the layer styling dock', 'Add group', 'Manage layer visibility', etc. Then, I will test to remove some of children of Layers Panel. I share the screenshot : https://1drv.ms/f/s!Amfzr7zpdbRqjF-ZV7ZoTva_50zR

Comment: @mega - You should ask this as a [new question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) as your original question was about hiding certain icons in toolbars. Your new question is asking how to remove icons on the Layers Panel dockwidget :)