# Removing buttons from QGIS Layers Panel

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

How to remove some icons (not all) on the Layers Panel dockwidget using python? Icons on the Layers Panel are :

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I have written the code :

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QDockWidget
for icon in iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget,'Layers').actions():
print icon.objectName()
```

with this code, nothing happen. So, I can not remove certain icon like in [Name of children of toolbar in QGIS python and how to disable?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228670/name-of-children-of-toolbar-in-qgis-python-and-how-to-disable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a direct way to access such buttons. It seems they were not given `objectName` values.

Nonetheless, an indirect way of accessing them is to go through controls in `Layers Panel` until getting the tool bar, which contains all buttons that you want to access:

```
widget = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget,'Layers').children()[5]
toolBar = widget.children()[1]
```

You can access buttons in order of appearance in the GUI. First button is `Open the layer styling dock`. The second one is `Add Group`, the third one is the `QWidgetAction` `Manage Layer Visibility` and so on.

I'll give you 2 examples:

Removing `Filter Legend by Map Content` button:

```
toolBar.actions()[3].setVisible(False) # Because it's the fourth button
```

Removing the whole `Manage Layer Visibility` widget action:

```
toolBar.actions()[2].setVisible(False) # Because it's in third position
```

---

*Note: Tested using QGIS v2.14.8*