# Remove many menubar in startup.py on QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, toolbar

I want to remove (not all) menubar with python. I will put the code in startup.py so that when loading QGIS, automatically just only one menu that is 'Project' menu. I get the code from [Finding the children name of menubar in QGIS Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229727/finding-the-children-name-of-menubar-in-qgis-python).

@xunilk and @Joseph gave the answer. The code :

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QToolBar, QDockWidget, QMenuBar
from qgis.utils import iface

for x in iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QMenuBar):
    print x.objectName()
for item in x.actions():
    print item
for i, item in enumerate(x.actions()):
    print i+1, 'name: ', item.icon().name()
for item in x.actions():
    if item.text().replace('&','') == 'Edit':
       item.setVisible(False)
    if item.text().replace('&','') == 'View':
       item.setVisible(False)
    if item.text().replace('&','') == 'Layer':
       item.setVisible(False)
    if item.text().replace('&','') == 'Settings':
       item.setVisible(False)
    if item.text().replace('&','') == 'Plugins':
       item.setVisible(False)
    if item.text().replace('&','') == 'Vector':
       item.setVisible(False)
    if item.text().replace('&','') == 'Raster':
       item.setVisible(False)
    if item.text().replace('&','') == 'Database':
       item.setVisible(False)
    if item.text().replace('&','') == 'Web':
       item.setVisible(False)
    if item.text().replace('&','') == 'Processing':
       item.setVisible(False)
    if item.text().replace('&','') == 'Help':
       item.setVisible(False)
```

All menus (except 'Project' menu) are successfully removed. Only three menus that not succeed to be removed. They are 'Database', 'Web', and 'Processing'. Why are these menus not removed, while I have written the code for them?

Comment: ok, it is work. I disable all plugin.

Comment: Glad it worked, will the post the comment as an answer for the convenience of others :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have **enabled** plugins which fall under those menubars, they will remain even after running your code.

Therefore, to completely remove the required menubars, make sure all plugins for the desired menubar is **disabled**.